# Create a new key mapping for mintty

Tags: cygwin, mintty

Mintty is a awsome terminal I used in window. Its full-screen feature make it an ideal solution
for using Vim. It can also be set to be transparent mode. I want to add a shortcut to toggle between
transparent mode, is there any one could give a starting point?

Answer (score 0):

There is no keyboard shortcut that will toggle transparency in mintty.  The closest to this may be the "Opaque when focused" option.